# Include assertion point success in the log

Tags: logging, coded-ui-tests, assertions

Hi I am now using Microsoft visual studio 2013 ultimate coded ui function. 
 After enable the log I realise that the log does not record down that my assertion points have pass the assertion point will only appear in the log is when it failed. Is there anyway to show the assertion points passed/success in the log?

Comment: Variations on this question are frequently asked. A web search should find lots of suggestions.

Comment: Erm I tried googling but the suggestion are mostly for vs2012 which have .trx file while in vs2013 I cant find that file

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to

```
Try
{
}
Finally
{
}
```

Remember assert is nothing more than a try/catch. Also Assert.Fail throws a horrible error message with "Assert.Fail" in the description.

Consider this

```
bool passed;


Try
{
     passed = MyTest.DoesSomethingExist(); 
     Assert.IsTrue(passed, "Nope it failed"); 
}
Finally
{
    Log("The test result: " + passed); 
}
```

Obviously that's a very basic example, but you can engineer the principles into your solution.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this with:

```
Assert.AreEqual(_control, "String");
Console.WriteLine("Assert X succeeded");
```

If it passes it will show "Assert X succeeded" in your log, else it will show the failure.

Comment: If that assert fails it will throw an exception and the remaining code won't execute.

Comment: Correct. But where in the question does it say he wants to continue on failure? As I read it he wants to see a message in his log whenever he passed an assertion.